# offsetWidth or CSS expression problem for IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, css, offsetwidth

I need to set the width of  textboxes as 80% of it's parent. So first I used

```
td input[type="text"]
{    
    width: 80%;
}
```

But it was not rendering properly if the `input` is the child of `td`. So, I used Css expressions

```
td input[type="text"]
{    
    width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth*0.8);
}
```

It is working as I wanted in every browser except IE 6. Can anybody help me, where I am going wrong? I know that expressions are allowed in IE 6. So, is it the problem of using css expression or something to do offsetWidth.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> td input[type="text"]

Attribute selectors don't work in IE6. If you want to support this browser, add a `class="text"` and style on `td input.text`.

You shouldn't need anything complex with scripts, jQuery or expressions.

Answer (score 1):

try rewriting as

```
* html td input[type="text"]
{    
    width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth*0.8) !important;
}
```

however my own alternative method would be to detect ie version and if its 6 redirect to an error page with a angry face alerting to the user : Its 21st Century you moron! Update!

:)

Comment: Yeah I also wanted to do that, but it's the client gahhh :X

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I am writing answer for my own question, thought if somebody can get help from this.

I tried many things from CSS, nothing worked in IE 6. So, finally used jquery

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substring(0, 1) == "6") {
            $("td > input[type='text']").each(function() {
                $(this).css("width", $(this).parent().width() * 0.80);
            });
        }
```

It worked for me fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is caused by the ie 6 box model. The width and height include the padding and the borders. [See here for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534304(VS.85).aspx).